# IntelliJ palette tool unavailable for Android

Tags: android, intellij-idea, palette

I've been trying to complete http://www.vogella.com/articles/Android/article.html#components in IntelliJ, my java editor of choice, but the palette tool seems to be unavailable. I know some of the other tools windows are only available after certain prompts, but I couldn't find a way to enable to palette.

This seems like an incredibly useful tool for quick UI development. It's a shame I can't get it to work.

Answer (score 2):

IntelliJ IDEA will have Android UI designer tool in version 12. At the moment you can use Eclipse for Android visual interface design.